# How can we set the default value of radio button in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a Model driven form and want to show the fields based on radio input.
Code :-

```
       <div class="form-group">
          <md-radio-group class="form-control"  id="radio1" formControlName="selection">
            <md-radio-button  [value]="A" >A</md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button  [value]="B">B</md-radio-button>
          </md-radio-group>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selection.value=='A'">
          <md-input-container>
              <textarea md-input placeholder="A" class="form-control"
                        formControlName="A"
                        style="border:none;"></textarea>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selection.value=='B'">
          <md-input-container>
            <input md-input placeholder="B" class="form-control"
                   formControlName="B"
                   style="border:none;">
          </md-input-container>            
        </div>
```

Getting error as "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"
As no radio is selected.

How can I specify to select the first one as default.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a `string` as a value for the radio. Right now Angular tries to find a variable with the name `A`.

```
<md-radio-group class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selection.value" 
                id="radio1" formControlName="selection">
  <md-radio-button [value]="'A'">A</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button [value]="'B'">B</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

You initialize the radio as you assign a value to `selection.value` in the according component:

```
class MyRadioComponent {
  selection = {"value":"A"};
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt,  But how will i say that select A as default when the page loads. Is there any property? And This is a reactive form, why ngModel in this. New to Angular. Please help

Comment: You need to tell Angular what to do when the radio input changes. You can do this, for instance, with ``[(ngModel)]`` or ``(change)``. See the last code example on md's github page: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6e4fe5e4172bb150f8d46c9f007ba2c2ff5bdf3a/src/components/radio/README.md

Comment: You can initialize your values in your component. Just assign ``selection.value`` a value of your choice, e.g in the constructor or right when declaring the variable. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.complexForm = fb.group({
                       'name': [null, Validators.required],
                       'description': [null, Validators.required],
                       'file': ["A", Validators.required],
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `selection` formControl is not yet created.There are two possible solution for this.

1. Use [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) ( `?.` ) as `*ngIf=selection?.value=='A'` while accessing the value of radio.

   ```
   <div class="form-group" *ngIf="selection?.value=='A'">
     <md-input-container>
         <textarea md-input placeholder="A" class="form-control"
                   formControlName="A"
                   style="border:none;"></textarea>
     </md-input-container>
   </div>
   ```
2. Prepare your form before the view is rendered.(i.e prepare your form in constructor of the component.)

and default value to any form control can be given when we create the form control.

for example in your case you can set default value of `selection` form control as follows.

```
let myForm = new FormGroup({ selection : new FormControl('A') })
```