# Angular 2/4 : Set one radio button checked defauk

Tags: angular, radio-button

I use radio button with angular 4, but I can't check by default one button and

My html :

```
<div>
                <span class="spanLabel"> 
                    <input class="option-input radio" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="filterQa" [value]="ALL" name="filterQa" /> ALL
                </span>
                <span class="spanLabel"> 
                    <input class="option-input radio" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="filterQa" [value]="IN" name="filterQa" /> INE
                </span>
                <span class="spanLabel">
                    <input class="option-input radio" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="filterQa" [value]="OUT" name="filterQa" /> OUTE
                </span>
                <span class="spanLabel"> 
                    <input class="option-input radio"   type="radio" [(ngModel)]="filterQ" [value]="Fermes" name="filterQ" /> TRED
                </span> 
                <span class="spanLabel"> 
                    <input class="option-input radio"   type="radio" [(ngModel)]="filterQ" [value]="Brouillon" name="filterQ" /> OUTESSS
                </span>
            </div>
```

In my comonent.ts

```
export class FoldersComponent implements OnInit {

  public filterQa;
  public filterQ;

..
}
```

How can I do for checking TRED and ALL by default ??

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558196/how-can-we-set-the-default-value-of-radio-button-in-angular-2.

Comment: Thhxxxx so much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we set the default value of radio button in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558196/how-can-we-set-the-default-value-of-radio-button-in-angular-2)